# Unable to use the lossless preset of the nvh265enc gstreamer plugin

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia, video-encoding

I'm working with gstreamer 1.18 (built with gst-build). I'm trying to use the lossless preset of the nvh265enc plugin. With the following pipeline, I can successfully use all presets except the lossless ones (lossless (6) and lossless-hp (7)):

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! nvh265enc preset=6 ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! glimagesink
```

Whenever I set `preset` to 6 or 7, I get the following error.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Got context from element 'nvh265dec0': gst.cuda.context=context, gst.cuda.context=(GstCudaContext)"\(GstCudaContext\)\ cudacontext0", cuda-device-id=(int)0;
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH265Enc:nvh265enc0: Could not configure supporting library.
Additional debug info:
../subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/sys/nvcodec/gstnvbaseenc.c(1712): gst_nv_base_enc_set_format (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH265Enc:nvh265enc0:
Failed to init encoder: 8
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH265Enc:nvh265enc0: Could not configure supporting library.
Additional debug info:
../subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/sys/nvcodec/gstnvbaseenc.c(1712): gst_nv_base_enc_set_format (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH265Enc:nvh265enc0:
Failed to init encoder: 8
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Freeing pipeline ...
```

What's more puzzling is that the lossless preset works with the samples from the Nvidia Video Codec SDK 9.

Did I miss any additional configuration?

EDIT : finally I found that adding `qp-const=0` or `rc-mode=1` to nvh265enc worked.

Comment: I would try to pass the encoded to a file a file instead of a decoder: `.. ! nvh265enc ! filesink`. The format requirements for the lossless preset may include something that the hardware decoder cannot decode.

Comment: According to the Video Encode and Decode GPU support matrix (https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new), my card (RTX 2080 Ti) should be able to decode h265 lossless streams.
Besides, by running a debugger, it looks like the initialization of the encoder fails due to wrong parameters. It surprises me that a preset provides invalid parameters...

Comment: Maybe there are better documents out there. But in that matrix I can only spot hints to "lossless" in the encoder section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, there is no difference between lossless and lossless-hp.

See https://superuser.com/questions/1528215/what-is-the-difference-between-nvenc-hevc-lossless-and-losslesshp-presets

Second of all, Gstreamer is not the application that Nvidia natively supports. FFmpeg, on the other hand, is. For example B-frames as reference mode with its two submodes (middle and each) is not supported too in GS. See: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/387613-Nvidia-h-265-hevc-lossless#post2509093

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -r 60 -hwaccel cuda  -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "in.mp4" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset lossless "out.mp4"
```

P.S. Gstreamer supports lossless with rc-mode=1 or qp-const=0.